# Copy data of one table from HBase 0.94 to HBase 0.98

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a cluster which runs on Hadoop 1.1.2 and HBase 0.94. Is there a way where I can copy HBase data to HDFS files, stop HBase, install HBase 0.98 and copy the data to HBase 0.98?

I am okay with downtime. I tried CopyTable and Import approaches which did not work.

Comment: Can you show here how you are trying copyTable and what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A rolling upgrade from 0.94.x directly to 0.98.x does not work. The upgrade path follows the same procedures as [Upgrading from 0.94.x to 0.96.x](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#upgrade0.96). Additional steps are required to use some of the new features of 0.98.x. See [Upgrading from 0.96.x to 0.98.x](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#upgrade0.98) for an abbreviated list of these features.

I think this should help you.

**Additional information which might be helpful:**

1. Taking backup of data is not required in any case.
2. If the migration is to a minor version -provided- a change in `HFile` version is not made, rolling update can be done.
3. Rolling update is not possible while migrating to a major version. In this case, we should run some scripts provided by the vendor to import data back into HBase. More information can be found along with the release of the product